# Passing parameters in dynamic link in arbitary order reactjs router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using Router to make dynamic links to a spesific page in reactjs

```
<Route path ="/editQuestions/" component ={EditQuestions}/>
```

what I want to do is to add two parameters , termId and questionId but in arbitary order
for example I want the page with `/editQuestions/termId/3/questionId/4`  to display the same content as the page `/editQuestions/questionId/4/termId/3` and I do not want to add two addition router elements , In addition to that I want the page to make default values to `questionId` , `termId` when they are not passed for example when using a link `/editQuestions/` I want it to display a page that ask the user to enter `questionId` and `termId`

conclusion : what I want to achieve is that modify the `Route` element so that it can accepts any number of the parameters in any order given without adding many other`Route` elements so that I keep my code elegant

Comment: The code've you shared already matches those urls. The disadvantage is that retrieving the parameters is less convenient compared to if you just did something like this `/editQuestions/termId/:termId/questionId/:questionId`. Also if it is just about `termId` and `questionId` you only need to handle two cases. The route path prop also allows an array of paths to match, so you still only need one route component for that. For the page that asks the user for `questionId` and `termId` a simple redirect would do it.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden my friend the idea is that may be in the future I pass many other parameters, handling many cases is tuff, so I want a way to handle all of them in  a single route, sth like `/(termid/:termId)?,(questionId/:questionId)?`
you can enter your parameters in whatever order and you can make any of them optional